# Create rows to parent tables for showing them in datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf, entity-framework

I have product price management application, where I can modify data of users, products and price lists. I use Entity-Framework. User can have only one price list and the price list have products which have been added to the application.

I have already done windows with datagrids for adding, modifying and deleting users and products.

I want to have datagrid which shows users price list, which is basically list of product and price data. Every user have same products.

The main problem is now creating the price list and showing its details in datagrid. When user is created in User Management window, it only creates a row to User table, so there isn't any price list data in database yet. I should have price list rows as many as there is Products added to db. **Should I create price list and price list rows at the same time when I create the new user? How I should implement that? Maybe stored procedures or C#?**

**Database tables:**

- **User**

  - Id
  - Name
- **Price list**

  - Id
  - User id (fk)
- **Price list row**

  - Id
  - Price
  - Price list id (fk)
  - Product id (fk)
- **Product**

  - Id
  - Name
  - Description
  - Price category id (fk)
- **Price category**

  - Id
  - Name
  - Option 1
  - Option 2
  - Option 3

Comment: Your users each have their own price list? Do they get a "default" template for the price list or how do you determine that? They get the stock price for all products or something?

Comment: @JacobH Yes, every user have different prices in the price list, but the products are same for every user. I didn't include table "Price category", which determines the type of price. One price category can be like 1, 2 or 3, so it's prices aren't normal currency. I don't think that's relevant to the question. I'll add the Price Category table to the question

Comment: @JacobH In the "price list" WPF window, I should be able to select User from combobox, and then datagrid shows user price list which includes product name, price, and a combobox, where new price can be selected of price category options.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I think you have at least one key backwards. Shouldn't each price list row have the ID of the price list and not the other way around? Else you will have a row in price list for each row in price list row. Then you would do 1) Insert User (return and store the inserted user id) 2) Insert price list header with @userid (return and store inserted price list id) 3) The insert a row for each product into price list row `Insert into [price list row] select product.id, @userid, @pricelistid from product`

Comment: Encapsulate the three steps in a stored proc makes the most sense. I can write up a full answer if you agree the key needs changed. Also if each price list row has a price what is the default for each? One of the category options? If so that join needs to be part of the select. If it's just 0 by default, that can be hard coded.

Comment: @JacobH Oh yes you are correct with that mistake in the db design. I'll edit that to question.

Comment: @JacobH Default price for the row can be a null, because it'll be set later with one of the category options.